# apexcharts w/vue, switching stackType doesn't render scale nor values correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

It looks like an ApexChart bug (or am I missing something) when I switch the chart.stackType from '100%' to 'normal'.

The '100%' stackType will render the Y-axis from 0 to 100 and show the numbers as percentage. 
When I switch dynamically from '100%' to 'normal' using Vue, the chart do not change it Y-axis nor the scale; it also do not change the way it show the values: it show the numeric value correct but add the '%' sign to them.

```
let x=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.options))
if(x.chart.stackType=='100%')
   x.chart={ stacked: true, stackType: 'normal' }
else
   x.chart={ stacked: true, stackType: '100%' }
this.options=x
```

To see it, here is a codePen: https://codepen.io/shprung/pen/poooGMK?editors=1010
Click on the button to toggle the stackType and you will see the Y-axis stay 0-100.

Do I need to set some "reset and rerender" via some API call I missed in the online documentation?